# how to wait for user input in Rasa chatbot?

Tags: chatbot, rasa

I want my rasa chatbot to wait for the user input and don't run the rest of the code until the user enters a text.

here is the pseudo code:

```
dispatcher.utter_message(text:'inter your name')
print('hi')
```

Rasa must wait for the user name and after the user entered a text `print('hi')` should run but currently, Rasa doesn't wait for user input and runs `print('hi')` instantly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Rasa `form` for getting the user's name here. The form is a control flow that helps to gather data from users. Each form has corresponding helper functions which will let you organize your messages during data gathering and after that. For reference pls check [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/forms) and see how `Submit` and `Validate` actions help.